# crashlytics- only first crash visible on dashboard

Tags: android, crashlytics

Blown away by the user interface so far in crashlytics but am puzzled why I only see the first crash registered in my dashboard and not any subsequent crashes.

Is there a toggle or preference that I need to configure if the crash is caused by the same line of code or is there sometimes a huge delay in dashboard updates?

Answer (score 0):

If it's the same exact crash then it will only show up once on the dashboard for that version of your app.

If you look at the one crash does it say it happened just once? If you force the app to crash using the API does that appear?

Answer (score 0):

If you have same crash multiple times, you can view all crashes in dashboard

[SO Viewing all crashes for a specific issue in Crashlytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30066920/viewing-all-crashes-for-a-specific-issue-in-crashlytics/30067525#30067525)