# Viewing all crashes for a specific issue in Crashlytics

Tags: android, ios, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I was wondering if it is possible to somehow view all the crashes (or non-fatals) for a particular issue from the Crashlytics dashboard.  Even though the exception is logged in the same place in the code, the stack trace and exception type/message may be different.  But since the exception is logged in the same place, Crashlytics treats it as the same issue.

As far as I can tell, you can only view the latest crash or non-fatal.  Is there a way?

Or alternatively, are there Crashlytics SDK calls that would allow me to differentiate the crashes?

Comment: As I know you are able to see all the issues and crashes on Crashlytics dashboard. Just login to your account and select the respective app with version if you are using versioning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can. To view all crashes for a particular issue follow this

1. Select the particular issue
2. In Next Screen you can use **Arrow mark** to see all crashes for a particular issue

[image]

 Here I have two crashes for the same Issue #4 with different date.

Comment: Thanks, bharat, that's it.  I hadn't noticed that before.